# Render post request in template Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-routing

I've been struggling a little getting the content of a form `post` request to render on a `results.erb` template.
here is my 
**petscontroller**:

```
class PetsController < ApplicationController

  # before_action :set_pet, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  PETFINDER = Petfinder::Client.new('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
  # GET /pets
  # GET /pets.json
  def results
    @animal_list = Pet.all
  def search # new
    @pet = Pet.new
  end
  end


  def create
    Pet.destroy_all
     @pets = PETFINDER.find_pets(pet_finder_type, pet_finder_zip, count: 500)
     if params['pets']['breed'].empty?
      @selected_animals = @pets.select do |pet|
        pet.age == params['pets']['age']  &&
        pet.size == params['pets']['size'] &&
        pet.sex == params['pets']['sex']
      end
    else
      @selected_animals = @pets.select do |pet|
        pet.age == params['pets']['age']  &&
        pet.size == params['pets']['size'] &&
        pet.sex == params['pets']['sex'] &&
        pet.breeds.include?(params['pets']['breeds'])
      end
    end



      @selected_animals.each do |selected_animal|
        @desired_pet = Pet.create(name: selected_animal.name)
        @desired_pet.age = selected_animal.age
        @desired_pet.size = selected_animal.size
        @desired_pet.sex = selected_animal.sex
        @desired_pet.breed = selected_animal.breeds
        # @desired_pet.picture = selected_animal.photos.first.medium
        @desired_pet.description = selected_animal.description
        @desired_pet.shelter_id = selected_animal.shelter_id
        @desired_pet.last_update = selected_animal.last_update
        @desired_pet.save
      end
    # binding.pry
  end
  private
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def pet_finder_type
      params[:pets][:type]

    end

    def pet_finder_zip
      params[:pets][:zip]

    end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
root 'welcome#index'

  get '/pets' => 'pets#search'

  post '/pets' => 'pets#create'

  get '/pets' => 'pets#results'
```

I'd like to be able to call all my `Pet` instances and render them in `pets/results.erb` iterate over it and get its values.
something like this:

**pets/results.erb**

```
<% @animal_pet.each do |pet| %>
<ul>
<li><%= pet.age %></li>
</ul>
<%end%>
```

I get a `Missing template pets/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/Users/cyrusghazanfar/Desktop/Purrfect-Match/app/views"` after I submit the a form in `search.erb`
Could someone help me set up a correct route and method here.

Comment: What controller method are you trying to call with your request?

Comment: put this link at end of create action.. 
redirect_to :controller=>'pets', :action => 'results'

Comment: I tried just tried that. it gives me a different error now:  `Petfinder::Error in PetsController#create
200: invalid arguments`  at `@pets = PETFINDER.find_pets(pet_finder_type, pet_finder_zip, count: 500)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails associates a view template with each of your controller actions. While a 'create' action isn't typically paired with a create view, Rails will attempt to redirect the output of the action to a create.html.erb template unless told otherwise. For example:

`def create
  @pets = PETFINDER.find_pets(pet_finder_type, pet_finder_zip, count: 500)
  ...
  redirect_to action: 'results'
end`

Will redirect the output to the `results` action of the current controller. This is all covered here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html